# What happens if number of processes greater than pid_max?

Tags: unix

Provided I do not edit the file : /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max. Therefore, I assume the maximum PID would be 32768.

What happens if I create 32769 simultaneous processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man fork` on OS X (and BSD based systems in general):

```
ERRORS
 Fork() will fail and no child process will be created if:

 [EAGAIN]    The system-imposed limit on the total number of processes under
             execution would be exceeded.
             This limit is configuration-dependent.

 [EAGAIN]    The system-imposed limit MAXUPRC (<sys/param.h>) on the total number
             of processes under execution by a single user would be exceeded.

 [ENOMEM]    There is insufficient swap space for the new process.
```